# Gazebo models available

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Dear Gazebo community,

I am looking for the gazebo models (with plugin) available, and I am not sure if there's another source than the gazebo's models folder.

Once I started a model and sent it to be included in the model library but I can't find it anywhere, does this library exist?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1402/gazebo-models-available/) by [Martí Morta - IRI](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/23/mart%C3%AD-morta---iri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 7 on 2013-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

https://gazebosim.org/models is the location where models can be download from. This is usually accomplished via the Gazebo GUI.

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models is the mercurial repository of the models. New models may be submitted via a pull-request.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0